# References or Standardization of "Value Updating" in Constraint Satisfaction

Tags: constraints

[Constraint Satisfaction Problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem) (CSPs) are basically, you have a set of constraints with variables and the domains of values for the variables. Then given some configuration of the variables (assignment of variables to values in their domains), you check to see if the constraints are "satisfied". That is, you check to see that evaluating all of the constraints returns a Boolean "true".

What I would like to do is sort of the reverse. Instead of this Boolean "testing" if the constraints are *true*, I would like to instead take the constraints and enforce them on the variables. That is, set the variables to whatever values they need to be in order to satisfy the constraints. An example of this would be like in a game, you say "this box's right side is always to the left of its containing box's right side," or, box.right < container.right. Then the constraint solving engine (like [Cassowary](https://constraints.cs.washington.edu/solvers/cassowary-tochi.pdf) for the game example) would take the box and set its "right" property to whatever number value it resolved to. So instead of the constraint solver giving you a Boolean value "yes the variable configuration satisfies the constraints", it instead updates the variables' configuration with appropriate values, "you have updated the variables". I think Cassowary uses the [Simplex Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) for solving its constraints.

I am a bit confused because [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction) says:

> **constraint satisfaction** is the process of finding a solution to a set of constraints that impose conditions that the variables must satisfy. A solution is therefore a set of values for the variables that satisfies all constraints—that is, a point in the feasible region.

That seems different than the *constraint satisfaction **problem***, of which it says:

> An evaluation is *consistent* if it does not violate any of the constraints.

That's why it seems CSPs are to return Boolean values, while in CS you can set the values. Not quite clear the distinction.

Anyways, I am looking for general techniques on Constraint Solving, in the sense of setting variables like in the simplex algorithm. However, I would like to apply it to any situation, not just linear programming. Some standard and simple example constraints are:

- All variables are different.
- box.right < container.right
- The sum of all variables < 10
- Variable a goes before variable b in evaluation.
- etc.

For the first case, seeing if the constraints are *satisfied* (Boolean true) is pretty easy: iterate through the pairs of variables, and if any pair is not equal to each other, return false, otherwise return true after processing all variables.

However, doing the equivalent of *setting the variables* doesn't seem possible at first glance: iterate through the pairs of variables, and if they are not equal, perhaps you set the first one to the second one. You might have to do some [fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration) thing, processing some of them more than once. And then figuring out what value to set them to seems arbitrary how I just did it. Maybe instead you need some further (nested) constraints defining how set the values (e.g. "set a to b if a > b, otherwise set b to a"). The possibilities are customizable.

In addition, for simpler cases like box.right < container.right, it is even complicated. You could say at first that if box.right >= container.right then set box.right = container.right. But maybe actually you don't want that, but instead you want some iPhone-like physics "bounce" where it overextends and then bounces back with momentum. So again, the possibilities are large, and you should probably have additional constraints.

> So my question is, similar to how for *testing* the constraints (for Boolean value) is standardized to CSP, I am wondering if there are any references or standardizations in terms of setting the values used by the constraints.

The only thing I have seen so far is that Cassowary simplex algorithm example which works well for an array of linear inequalities on real-numbered variables. I would like to see something that can handle the "All variables are different" case, and the other cases listed, as well as the standard CSP example problems like for scheduling, box packing, etc. I am not sure why I haven't encountered more on setting/updating constraint variables instead of the Boolean "yes constraints are satisfied" problem.

The only limits I have are that the constraints work on finite domains.

If it turns out there is no standardization at all and that every different constraint listed requires its own entire field of research, that would be good to know. Then I at least know what the situation is and why I haven't really seen much about it.

Answer (score 0):

CSP is a research fields with many publications each year. I suggest you to read one of the books on the subject, like Rina Dechter's.

For standardized CSP languages, check MiniZinc on one hand, and XCSP3 on the other.

There are two main approaches to CSP solving: systematic and stochastic (also known as local search). I have worked on three different CSP solvers, one of them stochastic, but I understand systematic solvers better.

There are many different approaches to systematic solvers. It is possible to fill a whole book covering all the possible approaches, so I will explain only the two approaches I believe the most in:

1. (G)AC3 which propagates constraints, until all global constraints (hyper-arcs) are consistent.
2. Reducing the problem to SAT, and letting the SAT solver do the hard work. There is a great algorithm that creates the CNF lazily, on demand when the solver is already working. In a sence, this is a hybrid SAT/CSP algorithm.

To get the AC3 approach going you need to maintain a *domain* for each variable. A domain is basically a set of possible assignments.

For example, consider the domains of `a` and `b`: D(a)={1,2}, D(b)={0,1} and the constraint `a <= b`. The algorithm checks one constraint at a time, and when it reaches `a <= b`, it sees that a=2 is impossible, and also b=0 is impossible, so it removes them from the domains. The new domains are D'(a)={1}, D'(b)={1}.

This process is called domain propagation. Using a queue of "dirty" constraints, or "dirty" variables, the solver knows which constraint to propagate next. When the queue is empty, then all constraints (hyper arcs) are consistent (this is where the name AC3 comes from).

When all arcs are consistent, then the solver picks a free variable (with more than one value in the domain), and restricts it to a single value. In SAT, this is called *a decision* It adds it to the queue and  propagates the constraints. If it gets to a conflict (a constraint can't be satisfied), it goes back and undos an earlier decision.

There are a lot of things going on here:

First, how the domains are represented. Some solvers only hold a pair of bounds for each domain. Others, have a set of integers. My solver holds an interval set, or a bit vector.

Then, how the solver knows to propagate a constraint? Some solvers such as SAT solvers, Minion, and HaifaCSP, use *watches* to avoid propagating irrelevant constraints. This has a significant performance impact on clauses.

Then there is the issue of making decisions. Usually, it is good to choose a variable that has a small domain and high connectivity. There are many papers comparing many different strategies. I prefer a dynamic strategy that resembles the VSIDS of  SAT solvers. This strategy is auto-tuned according to conflicts.

Making decision on the value is also important. Many simply take the smallest value in the domain. Sometimes this can be suboptimal if there is a constraint that limits a sum from below. Another option is to randomly choose between max and min values. I tune it further, and use the last assigned value.

After everything, there is the matter of backtracking. This is a whole can of worms. The problem with simple backtracking is that sometimes the cause for conflicts happened at the first decision, but it is detected only at the 100'th. The best thing is to analyze the conflict, and realize where the cause of the conflict is. SAT solvers have been doing this for decades. But CSP representation is not as trivial as CNF. So not many solvers could do it efficiently enough.

This is a nontrivial subject that can fill at least two university courses. Just the subject of conflict analysis can take half of a course.